# Jenkins workflow check if job is running or schedulled

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

is it possible to check if some job is running or scheduled from some workflow script?

Although it may seems enough to manage concurrency using stages:

```
stage name: 'stageName', concurrency: 1
```

and run builds in those stages like this:

```
build job: 'test-job', wait: false
```

it may happen that someone started the job ***test-job*** manually and I just want to handle that situation in my workflow script. For example by skipping the build or waiting till the build is finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works in flows that are not using ***Groovy Sandbox***:

```
for (Project job : Hudson.getInstance().getProjects()) {
    if (job.isBuilding() || job.isInQueue()) {
        echo "${job.getName()}"
    }
}
```

Comment: This will definitely not work in the sandbox. Also this style of `for`-loop does not currently work (you need to use a C-style loop with counter).