# Jenkins - check if specific job is running with hudson classes

Tags: jenkins, jobs

I need to check if specific job is running from another job. I dont want use API or plugins. Just bare hudson model.

I already tried some properties of  Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('folder/job').lastBuild but they either returning whole job status (stable/unstable) or there is no RUNNING results. I even seen that there is a script which finds current running executors. So i dont believe that there is no way of checking running jobs.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Find+builds+currently+running+that+has+been+executing+for+more+than+N+seconds

```
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.Result

@NonCPS
def getProject(projectName) {
    def project = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(projectName)
    if (!project) {error("Project not found: $projectName")}
    return project
}

project = getProject('folder/job')
build = project.lastBuild

def checkStatus2(){
    //return Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('folder/job').lastBuild.getResult()
    return Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('folder/job').lastBuild.buildStatusSummary.message
}

stage('check Job A status'){
    //def status = checkStatus2()
    //echo status
    //if(hudson.model.Result.RUNNING.equals(status)){
     if(build.@result == hudson.model.Result.NOT_BUILT){
        echo "running"
    }else{
         echo "not running"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a thread which gave me a hint
[Jenkins workflow check if job is running or schedulled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438601/jenkins-workflow-check-if-job-is-running-or-schedulled)

So i tried ...

```
 if(Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName('folder/job').isBuilding())
```

... and it works.